# Want to make Script constant on every Page load in WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

I have media player on a WordPress site which based on a script . Issue is that, when go to other menu the media player(script) is reloaded and starting from beginning again. I want to make that media player script constant on every page load so that the music will play non stop on background.

Comment: you should learn service worker using javascript in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need a one-page website or completely Ajaxify your existing theme.

I found a plugin which can do this - [https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajaxify-wordpress-site/], please give it a try[1](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajaxify-wordpress-site/)

Comment: Then you have to custom code your theme to make it ajaxifed